# When building to mobile the size of fonts reduce and became very small

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, uibutton, unityscript

Like I said in the title when i built to mobile the letter became too small. I think it is because phone has more pixel for his little screen.

Well I tried to fix text by simply making text to images in photoshop. But how can I make `InputField`s text (not the placeholder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, your Canvas' [CanvasScaler](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html)'s UI Scale Mode is probably set to **Constant Pixel Size**, and if your mobile device's resolution is too high, text will appear small.

[image: CanvasScaler]

Try changing the UI Scale Mode to **Scale With Screen Size** and change the properties it provides as needed.

(if your Canvas doesn't have a CanvasScaler component, click the Add Component button and add it)